# Creating war from its component folders

Tags: java, linux, zip, war, web-deployment

I have deployed my war file on a remote linux server. I run this war using jetty-runner. Its not feasible for me to push this war multiple time. Its size is huge and it takes aprrox 45 min to push a fresh war onto the server. To handle this issue I thought of using the following steps(with commands) :

1. `unzip:`Unzip war to its corresponding files/folders : WEB-INF, META-INF, index.jsp.
2. Updating new class file in WEB-INF.
3. `zip:`Repacking these folder into a war again.

But the newly created war does not work. Is there a standard/correct way to pack these files into a war. Also, `jar` command is not available on the server.
Please suggest.

**P.S.** Already looked into various SO questions but didn't find any useful solution.

Comment: It's best to upload via tomcat manager the war file.

Comment: Will it reduce upload time ? Also my query is for packing the files into a war file.

Comment: Yes, it will and much safer. I'll always upload my war file via tomcat manager

Comment: My 250 MB file takes 45 min. How would tomcat manager reduce this speed

Comment: That's very slow.. for me , my biggest war file i've uploaded was 319mb and it took me 4 minutes only.

Comment: My server does not allow such high speed. So I need to figure out a way to pack war on the server itself.

Comment: Do you have access to this url ? `http://localhost:8080/manager/html`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156256/discussion-between-aditya-gupta-and-freedompride).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The zip command does not work as expected. The war packed by that command did not work. Instead, we have to use the `JAR` command.

I was able to generate the war after modifying the contents by using :

> jar -cvf webproject.war index.jsp META-INF/ WEB-INF/

Note: If the jar command is not available on the server, specify `JAR` path using installed java on the server:

> PATH_TO_JAVA/bin/jar -cvf webproject.war index.jsp META-INF/ WEB-INF/